# Signed 2 year bond, then left

Tags: resignation, leave, employment-bond

I recently joined a company (Support Job) and signed a "Minimum service Tenure Agreement" for 2 Years, but the job was not good. So after 15 days I left them without informing them. (I was afraid that they would do something.)

After 1 month I got an “Unauthorized Absence of work" notice which stated that I needed inform HR why I took leave and give company assets. (I dont have any assets.)

I don’t want to join that company again. Can they put together a case?? They didn't given me any training.

What is best way to deal with situation?

Comment: This sounds like India - is it?

Comment: You probably won't get a relieving letter from them

Comment: The consequences of leaving without even telling them you are leaving are not likely to be good, but will depend on where you are working. Please add that information to your question. Incidentally, not everyone here is properly addressed as "sir". I suggest skipping the salutation.

Comment: This sounds like a scam, but you probably do need to consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend talking with an employment lawyer to get professional advice before making a decision on how to proceed. In my experience being bonded to a role tends to be linked to receiving some sort of unusual benefit, for example the company funds expensive training etc. In other words if you leave early you have to pay back the training cost. But it's difficult to provide any guidance or advice if we don't know the bond related provisions within your employment contract.